# Stuck on Texturing a Head With Projection Painting

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I am following along with Texturing a Head With Projection Painting as seen in this Youtube video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZDMFkj8GqA.  Everything goes correctly through unwrapping the UV's and putting the UV test grid on the model.  When I try to follow along and Projection Paint I get the image shown below, that comes along with a missing data message.  I don't see the Test Grid on the head & I don't know how to step back and rework the grid or add the Missing Texture that is referred to.  I think it may be time to start over with this exercise, but I don't know where I went wrong.  Any ideas would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: under that warning in the left panel there is a button, "add paint slot", use it: choose one, eg "diffuse" then you can paint over it.

Comment: I see no method to edit my original post.